# Why does useReducer first parameter get set to Value of dispatch?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The code below acts like useState (useReducer that is), but I can't find any document to explain why. However, I figured it out with the debugger.

```
const reducer = (state,action) => {
  return action;
};

const [email,setEmail] = useReducer(reducer,"");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of how the reducer was written:

```
const reducer = (state,action) => {
  return action;
};
```

Dispatched value is received as second `action` parameter in a reducer. New state is set to the value which was returned from a reducer, i.e. `action`. This way `useReducer` dispatch function works the same way as `useState` state setter. This is roughly what happens inside `useState`, since it uses `useReducer` internally.

It would behave differently if anything but `action` were returned.